# Jquery change width of input on hover and focus without queue

Tags: jquery

I want my input to change the width when hover or focus and change it back after leaving focus AND hover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tbRegex").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "200px"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "40px"
    });
  });

  $("#tbRegex").focus(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "200px"
    });
  });

  $("#tbRegex").blur(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "40px"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#tbRegex{width:40px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="tbRegex" type="text" placeholder="Text" />
  </body>

</html>
```

but i dont know how to tell that focus AND hover have to be left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of attributes like for example "isfocusedin" and set it to 1, on hover out you can fisrt check that focused is not 1

```
<input id="tbRegex" type="text" placeholder="Text" ishoveredin="0" isfocusedin="0" />
```

In hover out

```
if( $(this).attr("isfocusedin")!=1)
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "40px"
    });
```

**Working demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tbRegex").hover(function() {
     $(this).attr("ishoveredin",1);
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "200px"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).attr("ishoveredin",0);
    if( $(this).attr("isfocusedin")!=1)
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "40px"
    });
  });

  $("#tbRegex").focus(function() {
   $(this).attr("isfocusedin",1);
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "200px"
    });
  });

  $("#tbRegex").blur(function() {
     $(this).attr("isfocusedin",0);
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      width: "40px"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#tbRegex{width:40px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="tbRegex" type="text" placeholder="Text" ishoveredin="0" isfocusedin="0" />
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: great to hear that :)