# Expanding an input to fill a form

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to have a label and text box fill the width of a form.  I can't believe how much time I've wasted on this simple problem.  This would have been SO simple with tables.

Here's the simple HTML:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <style>
  * { box-sizing: border-box; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <form style="width: 500px; border-style:solid; border-color: red;">
  <label for="Txt">Label:</label>
  <input id="Txt" type="text" style="width: auto;" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's how it looks:

[image]

All I want is for my text box to fill the rest of the form (the empty area to the right of the text box.  I've tried 100%, display:table etc.  I want to solve it with HTML and CSS only (no JavaScript or jQuery), and without having to play around with pixel counts or percentages until it looks right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery change width of input on hover and focus without queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252869/jquery-change-width-of-input-on-hover-and-focus-without-queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `grid` layout by defining the grid template.

Here is the link to [Mozilla Docs for CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.form {
  width: 500px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label for="Txt">Label:</label>
  <input id="Txt" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm now a convert.  Grids are the best things ever!  It's amazing what they can do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

Use  `width: calc(100% - 82px);` for the input width

The 82px is equal to width of the label and (1px border * 2) of the input

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 82px);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form class="back">
  <label>Test Label</label><input type="text" name="search" class="">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a solution that's dependent on the label's pixel or percentage width, where I need to calculate for every label.

Comment: I didn't know about calc(), and it came in very handy for something else.  Thanks!

Comment: @uncaged if this answer helped u, then please accept it

Answer (score 1):

You should be use this simple way.

Please try: `width: calc(100% - 45px) !important;` into `input#Txt` class.

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```css
input#Txt {
width: calc(100% - 45px) !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form style="width: 500px; border-style:solid; border-color: red;">
        <label for="Txt">Label:</label>
        <input id="Txt" type="text" style="width: auto;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a solution that's dependent on the label's pixel or percentage width, where I need to calculate for every label.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox approach:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form style="width: 500px; border-style:solid; border-color: red;">
    <label for="Txt">Label:</label>
    <input id="Txt" type="text" style="width: auto;" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using browser-safe CSS rules, you can set width for label and input, then set them to `display: inline-block`, this way.

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10%;
        }

        input {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 88%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form style="width: 500px; border-style:solid; border-color: red;">
        <label for="Txt">Label:</label>
        <input id="Txt" type="text" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a solution that's dependent on the label's pixel or percentage width, where I need to calculate for every label.

Comment: I see. What you can do is set **input** to **max-width: 80%;**, this way, you make sure labels are always visible and not overlapped, and inputs with variable width.
The closest solution is to set both **input** and **label** to **display: inline-block** or float **label** to left and **input** to right, then make a clearfix for every field.